# file manipulation with out serverside coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload

Is it possible to manipulate a file only with client side programming? I am creating a text editor, which takes an uploaded file and need to save to another location after editing. Is it possible with client side coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everything you described is possible. Things you need are: the `FileReader` API for reading the files and `download` attribute of `a` for saving the with specific name. The solution won't be cross-browser but it'll work in the modern browsers.

- **Edit 1:** You can't to the manipulation like in language which have full access to the file system (i.e. you can't open files by their path for example). The user needs to drag the text file in the page which is your editor or select the file with `<input type="file" />`.
- **Edit 2:** The same is for saving the file. You can give the user a link with specified file name in the `download` attribute. When the user press this link the file will be saved in his download folder.

Comment: Minko Gechev, thnk u for the quick reply. Can i take the file using <input type="file" /> ?

Comment: Yes, your options are drag and drop, input type file or both combined.

Comment: Can u please explain a littile bit more about saving the file?

Comment: You just have to provide a link to the user. When he press this link the file will be saved in his download folder. Look at this:  http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download